# Evaluate$ \iint_S\frac{x+y+z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}ds$

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \iint_S\frac{x+y+z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}ds$ where $S$ is the unit disk centered at $(1,1,1)$ and lies on the plane $x+y+z=3$.

So my inegral becomes $\displaystyle \iint_S\frac{3}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}ds$. Now I change the coordinate system as $X=x-1,Y=y-1,Z=z-1$ in order to shift the center to $(0,0,0)$.

Then, I have $\displaystyle \iint_S\frac{3}{((X+1)^2+(Y+1)^2+(Z+1)^2)^{3/2}} \, ds$.

And then I was going to change this to $(r,\theta)$ system since now $(X+1)^2+(Y+1)^2+(Z+1)^2=r^2$. Is this correct? I mean doesn't that coordinate change does anything to $ds$?

Comment: your change of variables isn't well-defined. Use spherical coordinates

Comment: After the correct change of variables, $ds = r dr d\theta$

Comment: I think use of spherical coordinates is so complicated. Is there a method to solve this integral without doing any coordinate change?

Comment: What is $S$? Your wording is a little ambiguous. Can you write down equations defining it?

Comment: @pre-kidney: No. I have written down it clearly. That wording makes sense rather than equations.

Comment: What is the dimension of $S$?

Comment: It is $2$, since it is a part of a plane.

Comment: Suggestion: in the original coordinates: since the line through the origin $O=(0,0,0)$ and the center $p=(1,1,1)$ of your disk is perpendicular to the plane $\Pi:x+y+z=3$, you can use Pythagoras to express $(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2+(z-0)^2$ in terms of $r$, where $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates parametrizing the unit disc centered around $p$ in the plane $\Pi$. ($ds$ is as @toliveira writes.)

Comment: Ok. So my integral becomes $\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{3rdrd\theta}{(r^2+3)^{3/2}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta - yes... Sorry for not answering earlier, I was on the road.